# What are the available approaches to show our meeting rooms' calendars inside sharepoint online modern site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, calendar, active-directory, sharepoint-calendar

I am working on a SharePoint online team site (classic team site), which have some modern UI pages. and we have our meeting rooms created inside our Active directory, and those meeting rooms have exchange calendars. so now our customer is asking to show those meeting rooms' calendars inside a modern UI page. so inside the modern UI, we will have the following:-

1. The meeting Room Name.
2. Under the meeting room name we want to show its calendar, so users can know when the meeting room will be free and when it is occupied.
3. we have around 8 meeting rooms.

so I am not sure what are the available approaches within SharePoint online to achieve this? or are there any third party web parts or libraries which can allow us to achieve this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use the calendar overlay to let the Exchange Online calendar display in the SharePoint Online.

It is because the ability to use the calendar overlay in a SharePoint Online calendar that is retrieved from Exchange Online isn't supported. For more information, please read [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2997170).

And we cannot create a calendar with resources in SharePoint Online since there is not `EnableResourceSelector` property for SharePoint Online list.

To achieve your requirement, you may need to develop the custom solution.

Comment: Now I already excluded the calendar overlay option, because as i know calendar overlay will only allow to show the current user logged-in calendar.. and i can not rely on this option to show the calendaers for the meeting rooms...

Comment: Yes. A simple idea, one calendar as one room. create a summary calendar, overlay it with these room calendars.

Comment: can you please advice more on what do you exactly mean in your last comment ?

Comment: create a SP calendar as a meeting room. if someone wants to book this meet room, add event in this calendar.

Comment: thanks for the advice and reply. now in our case we still want the users to send email directly to the exchange meeting room and book a meeting. in addition to that we want to show the exchnage calendar inside sharepoint modern page,so users can know when the meeting room will be free, before booking a meeting... so we do not want to replace the meeting room exchange calendar with sharepoint calendar... so i am not sure if showing an exchnage calendar inside sharepoint is a supported operation ?

Comment: The ability to use the calendar overlay in a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server calendar that is retrieved from Exchange Online isn't supported. I'm afraid you may need to build a custom solution if you want to display exchange calendar in SPO.